# How to deal with unbalanced design (lmer/glmer)?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I have a genetic study design where we are interested in the effects of genes on a phenotype.
I have setup an experiment where I have extracted two alleles from individuals from 9 different places around the world. For simplicity I have labelled them A-I

[image]

As you can see from the image above, we have strains of fly that have a full factorial combination of each allele.

The problem is that one combination is inviable (no living progeny), and we cannot measure any phenotype from this line.

**Question:**
I would like to analyse any data from this using lmer/glmer

trait ~ gene1 * gene2

however, the design is incomplete...
What is the best way to go forward with this design?
Ideally I'd lie to get the contribution of each gene to the trait (plus their interaction).

many thanks!

Comment: I think you need to include the count data to get an answer.